# C++ Nullptr vs Null-Object for potential noop function arguments?

Tags: c++, optional-parameters, null-object-pattern

**TL;DR** : Should we use `fn(Interface* pMaybeNull)` or `fn(Interface& maybeNullObject)` -- specifically in the case of "optional" function arguments of a virtual/abstract base class?

---

Our code base contains various forms of the following pattern:

```
struct CallbackBase {
  virtual ~CallbackBase() = default;
  virtual void Hello(/*omitted ...*/) = 0;
};
...

void DoTheThing(..., CallbackBase* pOpt) {
  ...
  if (pOpt) { pOpt->Hello(...); }
}
```

where the usage site would look like:

```
... {
  auto greet = ...;
  ...
  DoTheThing(..., &greet);
  // or if no callback is required from call site:
  DoTheThing(..., nullptr);
}
```

It has been **proposed** that, going forward, we should use a form of the Null-Object-Pattern. like so:

```
struct NoopCall : public CallbackBase {
  virtual void Hello(/*omitted ...*/) { /*noop*/ }
};

void DoTheThing2(..., CallbackBase& opt) {
  ...
  opt.Hello(...);
}

... {
  NoopCall noop;
  // if no callback is required from call site:
  DoTheThing2(..., noop);
}
```

Note: Search variations yield lots of results regarding Null-Object (many not in the C++ space), a lot of very basic treatment of pointer vs. references and if you include the word "optional", as-in the parameter is optional, you obviously get a lot of hits regarding `std::optional` which, afaik, is unsuitable for this virtual interface use case.

I couldn't find a decent comparison of the two variants present here, so here goes:

Given C++17/C++20 and a halfway modern compiler, is there any expected difference in the runtime characteristics of the two approaches? (this factor being just a corollary to the overall design choice.)

The "Null Object" approach certainly "seems" more modern and safer to *me* -- is there anything in favor of the pointer approach?

---

Note:

I *think* it is orthogonal to the question posed, whether it stands as posted, or uses a variant of overloading or default arguments.

That is, the question should be valid, regardless of:

```
//a

void DoTheThing(arg);

// vs b

void DoTheThing(arg=nullthing);

// vs c

void DoTheThing(arg); // overload1
void DoTheThing(); // overload0 (calling 1 internally)
```

Comment: `is there any expected` Why compare expectancy? Why not just compare the actual generated assembly?

Comment: @KamilCuk - I guess that would be part of the answer, now would it? I can craft an example and run it through Godbolt, but that would only answer the specific of the (dummy) example. References to such an experiment could certainly be included in an answer.

Comment: @wohlstad - You are right - I oversimplified in the question. Will correct.

Comment: why not making an overload? One with and one without callback?

Comment: Overall, https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub do not optimize. Prefer to write more clear and more safe code. Second approach is better, as you don't have to check for `pOpt` to be null every time you use it, saving yourself from potential segfault.

Comment: @Raildex - Because the implementation of the overload without would then need to call the other implementation with leads us back to the original question, I think.

Comment: @KamilCuk - The perf part is just a part of the design choice. This being C++, it always pops up, so I included it in the question. I agree, in general, don't sweat the nanoseconds.

Comment: In general I would also prefer the 2nd approach for the reason mentioned by @KamilCuk. But it's somewhat a matter of personal preference.

Comment: In the case of null object the user code is more "decoupled" in the sense that it makes less assumption about it. It doesn't need to handle null and it doesn't need to provide an override, it just calls the method. IMHO, that's the more important difference between them.

Comment: There is an completely non-virtual approach to callback handling. Allow the registration of std::function<retval_t(args_t...)> as callbacks. This is even more decoupled, can accept any function with the correct signature (which might also reduce the amount of compile time checking though). Default the callback to []{} to do nothing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer - the "problem" with std::function is that it is a bit more like the ptr approach, as a fn *can* be empty so the inside code would then again need to be written as `if(fn) { fn(); }` to make it work with passing arbitrary callbacks through.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: using erased type `std::function` is similar to virtual call (internally).

Comment: @MartinBa That's why the callback must be initialized with an empty lambda. The whole idea is not to have if's in your code. Also usually I have code with std::vector<std::function<...>> (multiple callback registrations) so then you just have an empty vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure, but with less of the custom callback base classes, and more reuse of what the standard library offers. I was not proposing this for a run-time performance gain. But overal maintainability and reduced cyclomatic complexity in developer code (with respect to nullptr checks)

Answer (score 0):

#### Performance:

I inspected the [code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzLGkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XEJCnUNTdmtQ109xaUDAJS2qF7EyOwcQ8ReDgDUABKVtKgAIkx1WyYA7FYaAIJbW8EE92exh1saJrFXt1toDEM/CHqACotgpnq9zGZIR8vhdDjCTDdEdd1ptHm4xLQIkxkABrCxMJRnS7Iu4ANzwDS8Yi2AD8MbQsTj8YTMBBZuCtlgqEwvLQCAibuTKQRqbQtmTUHh0Lt9qgIHtGUcTkwfgIhuYAGxcjkfV7vT7IuGC67I1HbUKoVCJBn0YhbGjMcUgLa27F4glEi5fYVUmmS6WypUKuXHU6/DVmTUc1Bk6LEaWYYkWLYAeiBDCtiSBqeJ8KR53hhqRN2CtGCSct1tt0S2VcSJuRDy2ACVMAo%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%2B8sImIY6PCwIqCATFhTvmKgDGABRFpWtbAs22QRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQ/t0VoDCMFBrGsfQ8AiMrIHmFT0lB1MhnQVmIssMwNDTYCzElvBSsqG70hcBh3E8Zp/GVqY%2BhiVpcjSARRhaJIUj1hhNZKfpxnloGBE6EZVbGNoFZt4ZugraYLdsF2Db0CYGjNmYuHmBRopWCRvL8wq/tCjgtimyQthYBQuolIatNG8bx1wQgSHneLZl4W6tFmVL0uysvMty%2BGCtIQLguj0rysq97qpgRAUBI9rmooCA2qamJgC4MwzH%2BzA5swQnVsSda7r4OgxuIXb9r%2B87jphlfLuuhwYYexgCGe16is%2B77fuCgGFZBorwch6GZ8o%2BHgsR5HLtR1ZgoxvAsbunG8YJpbJ%2Bn0mghybiCpvwGmSg1BFV0MPZmxg2aWA5lzeAvMwL804OhYCsQ5btGcBAVw3tWiBDdlrHIxtqgEKNnkdI/sPZ2CdjUL29tDZ0OtgwyYxDzba09l0ChvtXZFBIYHBYSxQ5CPhv5GuRVo6xwAByanQtNLYwBkDIC2IPLS0sIBZyIPaOKgcC5VRLvEDK5cy55Q4NXWuvB662EboXFK5izCRzriVJuRd5hxgXorSQQA%3D%3D%3D) and while MSVC shows "the obvious", the gcc output is interesting (see below).

// [Gist for a MCVE](https://gist.github.com/bilbothebaggins/5a1d83ba0b5759e6481caff543c46246).

*"The obvious"* is that the version with the Noop object contains an **unconditional** virtual call to `Hello` and the pointer version has an additional pointer test, eliding the call if the pointer is null.

So, if the function is "always" called with a valid callback, the pointer version is a pessimization, paying an additional null check.

If the function is "never" called with a valid callback, the NullObject version is a (worse) pessimization, paying a virtual call that does nothing.

**However**, the object version in the gcc code contains this:

```
WithObject(int, CallbackBase&):
...
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
...
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+16]
   (!)  cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:NoopCaller::Hello(HelloData const&)
        jne     .L31

.L25:
...

.L31:
        mov     rdi, rsi
        mov     rsi, rsp
        call    rax
        jmp     .L25
```

And while my understanding of assembly is certainly near non existent, this *looks like* gcc is comparing the call pointer to the `NoopCaller::Hello` function, and eliding the call in this case!

#### Conclusion

In general, the pointer version should produce more optimal code on the micro-level. However, compiler optimizations *might* make any difference near non-observable.

- Think about using the pointer version if you have a very hot path where the callback is null.
- Use the null object version otherwise, as it is arguably safer and more maintainable.